# CSS Header Border bottom

Tags: css, sass

How do you achieve this kind thing on the bottom of a div in CSS?

[image]

I try

```
 &:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 133.93px;
  height: 93.63px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background-image: $gradeint;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  top: -10%;
  right: 0;
}
```

but that not something I want

Comment: Put the background into your before pseudo element and use clip-path on it to get the right shape of the blue bit.

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve something like the shape using the [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property. Here's an example.

The purple area actually covers the whole container, but the `clip-path` set on it clips it to the polygon defined by the points `0 0, 100% 0, 35% 60%, 0 0` where `0, 0` is the top-left corner of the container and `100%, 100%` would be the bottom-right corner.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.accent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: purple;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 35% 60%, 0 0);
}

.image {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 125px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="accent"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much